# Reheating a Pretzel

Tags: reheating

I bought a large soft pretzel at a pretzel shop yesterday. When you buy them, they are warm and soft. What's the best way to reheat it so that it's as though I just bought it?

Answer (score 5):

It'll never be the same as when it's new. The closest I've ever seen is a method often used for good bagels: put in paper bag with a bit of water and nuke it. Basically just reheat it with a lot of humidity.

Comment: I have always wrapped it in a damp paper towel, then nuked it for about 30 seconds.

Comment: Do you close the paper bag? Where do you place the water? On the pretzel? At the bottom of the bag? (This last method seems like it would cause a mess.)

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping in foil gently and heating in a toaster oven until warmed through.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can make your pretzel as nice as it was when purchased fresh. First set it on a piece of tin foil large enough to completely wrap it. Second, add about 1 table spoon of water per pretzel then wrap as tightly as possible.

Proceed to place pretzel in oven at 250 degree for about 20 minutes.

There you have it. Your pretzel like new.

Comment: Is that 250°C or 250°F?